# plot lmer result in faceted ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, lmer

I'm analysing some repeated measures drug trials data and I'm not sure how to plot the lmer results when using faceted ggplots. I have made an initial plot of the individual slopes from the master dataset, but I'm doing the lmer analyses separately by sex.

Using publicly available data, which has only 2 treatment groups compared to the four I have, this is the replicable example below. It uses the `reshape2`, `lme4`, and `ggplot2` packages.

```
CatAnx <- read.fwf(file=("http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~winner/data/cats_anxiety1.dat"),
               widths=c(-6,2,-5,3,-5,3,-7,1,-7,1,-7,1,-7,1,-7,1,-6,2,-6,2,-6,2,-6,2,-6,2))
colnames(CatAnx) <- c('ID','Weight','Age_Months','Gender','Environment','Origin','Treatment','Result','EmoTime1','EmoTime2',
                  'EmoTime3','EmoTime4','EmoTime5')
library("reshape2")
CatAnxRM <- melt(CatAnx, id.vars=c("ID", "Gender", "Treatment"), measure.vars=c("EmoTime1", "EmoTime2", "EmoTime3",
                                                                            "EmoTime4", "EmoTime5"))
CatAnxRM$Sex <- with(CatAnxRM, ifelse(Gender==1, "Neut Female", ifelse(Gender==2, "Neut Male", "Whole Female")))
CatAnxRM$Time <- with(CatAnxRM, ifelse(variable=="EmoTime1", 1, ifelse(variable=="EmoTime2", 2, ifelse(variable=="EmoTime3", 3,
                                  ifelse(variable=="EmoTime4", 4,5)))))
CatAnxRM.Male <- subset(CatAnxRM, Gender=="2")
library("lme4")
Male.lmer <- lmer(value ~ Treatment * Time + (Time + 1|ID), data=CatAnxRM.Male)
library("ggplot2")
AnxScores<-ggplot(CatAnxRM, aes(Time, value, colour=Sex))+
geom_line(aes(group = ID))+
labs(x="Time Anxiety Measured", y="Anxiety Score", title="Effect of Zylkene on Anxiety")+ 
facet_grid(. ~ Treatment)
AnxScores
```

Information about the dataset [is here](http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~winner/data/cats_anxiety1.txt).

How do I plot the correct summary line from lmer in both facets, which differ on the basis of `Treatment`?

In my real life example, I'll also be analysing the females so there will be two sets of lines to plot per facet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a data frame (e.g. `lines.df`) with intercept (e.g. `int`) and slope (`slo`) variables where each line of the df corresponds to one facet, then plot over the top:

```
+ geom_abline(aes(intercept = int, slope = slo), data = lines.df)
```

Comment: As I will have two lines per facet, do I need to add a Sex indicator to `lines.df` so I can get the correct number of lines per facet?

Comment: You could either add `sex` to `lines.df` and have two lines for each facet with one sex for each, and add e.g. `colour=sex` of `linetype=sex` to `aes` or add a second data frame and call it too with an extra line of code

Comment: I'm getting all four lines to plot in every facet, how do I instruct ggplot which row in lines.df to plot per facet? This is four lines, and not two, because I've implemented in my real work and not the example.

Comment: I think I fixed it by adding in the value of the Treatment, and now it knows in which facet to draw each line.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't entirely clear what you mean by 'correct summary line', but I've adapted the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23330097/how-to-predict-and-graph-non-linear-varying-slopes-in-lmer-or-glmer) to your data. Is this the output you need?

```
newdata <- with(CatAnxRM.Male, expand.grid(Treatment=unique(Treatment),
                                           Time=unique(Time), Sex = unique(Sex),
                                           ID=unique(ID)))

newdata$pred <- predict(Male.lmer, newdata)

p <- ggplot(newdata, aes(x=Time, y=pred, colour=Sex, group=ID))
p + geom_line() + ggtitle("Varying Slopes") + 
    facet_grid(. ~ Treatment)
```

And get the following output

[image: Random slopes plot]

Comment: Hi r.bot, what I'm after is the original facets plot, with a mean line from the lmer results overplotted on each facet. I'm trying to visual essentially the group averages (sex with treatment) on top of the raw lines so I can get a sense of overall change. So, if it was an OLS regression, the overplot would be the line-of-best fit, on top of the individual slopes.